# Setting the title for pdf content page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, pdf

I am using Jasper to generate reports on my server. When I serve the pdf, I display it in a new tab using `target="_blank"` in the form that is sent to the Servlet. In the servlet, I am using response.setContentType("application/pdf") to serve the page as a pdf.

How do I set the title of the pdf page (the title that shows up in the tab)?

Comment: Did you find answer for this?? I am needing solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Since its not an HTML page, the tab title will be the filename.  You can set the filename like:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename="+filename);
```

If you need spaces in the filename, you'll need quotes (escaped, of course):

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\""+filename+"\"");
```

Of course you can hardcode it:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"Some report name.pdf\"");
```